# Cannot implicitly convert type MVC.Table1 to MVC.Models.prodInfo

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I am working with ASP.Net MVC, just a beginner. Trying to get a good understanding of it. However I am getting this error:

**Cannot implicitly convert type MVC.Table1 to MVC.Model.prodInfo**

Here is my code:

**Model**

```
namespace MVC.Models
{
    public class Sample
    {
        Database_Entity db;

        public Sample()
        {
            db = new Database_Entity();
        }

        public List<prodInfo> getStuff()
        {

            var que = (from wr in db.Table1
                       join wrc in db.Table2 on wr.ID equals wrc.ID
                       join cd in db.Table3 on wrc.ID equals cd.ID
                       select new prodInfo
                       {
                           Short_ID = wr.ID,
                           Planned_Date = cd.Planned_Date.ToString(),
                           Actual_Date = cd.Actual_Date.ToString()
                       }).ToList();
            return que;
        }
    }

    public class prodInfo
    {
        public string Short_ID { get; set; }
        public string Planned_Date { get; set; }
        public string Actual_Date { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Controller**

This is where the error occurs in the **Edit(String ID)** method...

```
namespace MVC.Controllers
{
    public class HelloController : Controller
    {
        Database_Entity db;
        // GET: Hello
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            Sample sam = new Sample();
            return View(sam.getStuff());
        }

        public ActionResult Edit(string ID)
        {
            if (ID == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);  
            }
            prodInfo item = db.Table1.Find(ID);
            if (item == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(item);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Edit(prodInfo model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Entry(model).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            return View(model);
        } 

    }
```

**prodInfo item = db.Table1.Find(ID);** This line is causing the error. I don't understand what is wrong, If anyone can help me out that would be great. If needed, I will add the View class in the edits.

Comment: Well, `db.Table1.Find(ID);` returns an object with type `Table1`, not `prodInfo`. If you want a `prodInfo`, you'll need to convert it...

Comment: Would you mind giving an example, because I don't know if there is a built in function that does it for you.

Comment: You already have an example in your `getStuff` function... In fact, you could just add a `getProdInfoByID(string ID)` function that does the same thing as `getStuff`, but adds a `where` clause, and returns `FirstOrDefault()`

Comment: Cannot implicitly convert type MVC.Models.prodInfo to System.Generic.List<MVC.Models.ProdInfo>.

Comment: You need to convert your entity to the DTO/ViewModel. I like to use AutoMapper for that, but you can do it manually as you did above. Try `prodInfo item = db.Table1.Where(t => t.ID == ID).Select(x => new prodInfo { Short_ID = x.ID, Planned_Date = x.Planned_Date, Actual_Date = x.Actual_Date});`

Comment: Check my answer please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new method in your Sample class:

```
    public prodInfo GetProdInfo(string ID)
    {
        var pInfo = (from wr in db.Table1
                   join wrc in db.Table2 on wr.ID equals wrc.ID
                   join cd in db.Table3 on wrc.ID equals cd.ID
                   select new prodInfo
                   {
                       Short_ID = wr.ID,
                       Planned_Date = cd.Planned_Date.ToString(),
                       Actual_Date = cd.Actual_Date.ToString()
                   }).FirstOrDefault(x=>x.Short_ID == ID);
        return pInfo;
    }
```

and modify your Edit method in HomeController by calling the new method:

```
var result = sam.GetProdInfo(ID);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well! When you want to get data from database using `Entity-Framework`, the return type of data is type of `DatabaseModel`.

For Fixed this you have to get data like `var` and map to your object. like:

```
namespace MVC.Controllers
{
    public class HelloController : Controller
    {
        Database_Entity db;
        // GET: Hello
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            Sample sam = new Sample();
            return View(sam.getStuff());
        }

        public ActionResult Edit(string ID)
        {
            if (ID == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);  
            }
            var result = db.Table1.Find(ID);
            if (item == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(new prodInfo(){
                                /////
                                });
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Edit(prodInfo model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Entry(model).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            return View(model);
        } 

    }
```